# ALTER DATABASE returning Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am attempting to recreate a SQL Server Compact database from a script. I started off creating it like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDatabase]
GO
```

and that seemed to work. The next commands in the script are these:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
```

and about two dozen similar commands. I have tried a representative sample of these and they all return the error:

> *Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
>
>   ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
>
>   There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 7,Token in error = DATABASE ]*

Does anyone know what the matter is?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174454(v=sql.90).aspx, I don't think you can do `alter database` in SQL Server CE.